# TikZ simple nodes and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am completely new to `TikZ` and am trying to draw some basic shapes for a title page.

I would like to right-align a label in the top right corner of a `node` in order for it to stay in place no matter the length of said label.
I got close to what I want but if the label is too long then it overflows the page.

I am pretty sure that this is far from being the best way to do so and am completely open to suggestions.

#### Bonus questions

I have not yet research these matters yet but I figure I could just ask:

1. Is it possible to keep the positioning of the node similar without a rectangle around in order to remove the border?
2. Could I set minimal dimensions for the title container but have it expand depending on the width of the label?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (.1\textwidth,1);
      \fill[blue] (.12\textwidth,0) rectangle (\textwidth,1);
      \filldraw[draw=black,fill=white] (.05\textwidth,-0.5) rectangle (.4\textwidth,1.5) node[pos=0.5] {Title};
      \draw (0,-.5) rectangle (\textwidth, 1.5) node[pos=.9] {Some very long subtitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: actual]

Comment: Try `anchor=east` instead of `pos=.9`. But what are you actually trying to do? There is probably an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing somewhat - do you want something like this?

[image: title layout]

`minimum width` and `minimum height` can be used as options for `node`s to do what they say on the tin i.e. the node will expand, if necessary. By placing `node`s directly rather than using paths to place them, we can make use of `anchor` to determine their placement. `anchor=north east` uses the upper right corner of the node for placement. If we place this at the top right corner of the text block, we get what (I think) is desired.

I think it is easier to draw the red/blue lines after placing the nodes, using the `backgrounds` library to put the lines behind the `title` node.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (subtitle) [anchor=north east] at (current page text area.north east) {Some very, very, very, repetitive and long subtitle};
    \node (title) [draw, fill=white, anchor=north west, minimum width=.35\textwidth, minimum height=20mm] at ([xshift={.05\textwidth+\parindent}, yshift=-0.5]current page text area.north west) {Title};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \draw [red, line width=10mm] (title.west -| current page text area.west) -- (title.center);
      \draw [blue, line width=10mm] (title.center) -- (title.west -| current page text area.east) ;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Or you might want

[image: closer fit]

which can be achieved by zeroing the `inner xsep` for the `subtitle` node:

```
\node (subtitle) [anchor=north east, inner xsep=0pt] at (current page text area.north east) {Some very, very, very, repetitive and long subtitle};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I am unsure if I understand correctly the meaning of `-| current page text area.west` though. What does it do exactly?

Comment: @Florian It aligns with an anchor at the west point of the current page's text area. The `-|` means that you're using the `y` value from the coordinate before and the `x` value from the coordinate after. So, here, you're using the `x` from that particular anchor, but the `y` from somewhere else. `tikzpagenodes` provides anchors relative to the page layout, beyond the defaults which are built-in. These include anchors for the text block, which is what I'm using here. Does that make sense?